# chrome jquery expand height animation flickers

Tags: jquery

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KXQyZ/1/

Oddly enough it doesn't occur upon shortening the height.

It runs smoothly as expected in IE9 and Firefox.  It lags slightly in Safari, but I'm fine with that.  It is only chrome that has an annoying flicker.

I was wondering if this is a straight limitation of the javascript engine, or if there was a work-around of sorts.  I don't think it has anything to do with machine hardware, as I tried on my machine at work, which has too much ram, and a beast of a cpu.

Windows 7: Versions
Firefox: 15.0.1
Chrome: 22.0.1229.79 m
IE9: 9.0.8112.16421
Safari: 5.1.7

Comment: for me, it ran the worst in firefox, best in ie and was 'good enough' in chrome.

Comment: i just updated my version of firefox and it was still a bit jittery... about the same as chrome

Comment: I take it you're not on a mac?  I'm just trying to narrow down what the meaningful difference is.  The laptop I found this out on has decent specs, so I haven't tried it on a lower end computer.  I also haven't tried it on MacOS or windows xp.

Comment: I'm on a lappy running Windows 7

Comment: You might want to try CSS animations/transitions instead of Javascript ones

Comment: Ah - I didn't think of that.  I'll give it a shot when I'm back from work.

Thanks for the feedback - and if you answer with that I'll mark it as correct assuming testing goes fine.